# HTACCESS url in page REDIRECT

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a url condo-search.co and it loads a blank page, I want to direct it to condo-search/en/index.php how do i do that using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /en/index.php
```

in your document root's htaccess file. Or if you want it to not externally redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /en/index.php [L]
```